# Creating data map for game map like apple do in "Adventure"

Tags: ios, iphone, sprite-kit

I have created a map for a level which is 1152x640px big, i have split it up into 9x5 tiles which are 128x128px big. I use these in my spritekit game to lay out the background for the level.

In the example game "Adventure" apple have provided they do the same thing with the tiles, they then use a data map to generate invisible collision walls. I'm trying to achieve  the same thing but i cant figure out how to create the data map for my game map. How can this be done?

My map: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NluPJ.png

I want a data map that specifies where the walls are in my map so i can generate them in code only using that data map.

My problem is i cant figure out how to create the data map nor how they convert the coordinates from a pixel in the data map to a world point in apples example. I have searched alot on the web for an answer to this but I cant find anything.

Is this an unneccesarily complicated way to accomplish what i need? or is there any easier way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in the Adventure game they actually just place SKSprites down onto their map with SKPhysicsBodys on them.

To do something like this you just need the frame of each wall.

You could store this in a plist as an array of dictionaries. Something like...

```
[
    {
        x: @10,
        y: @100,
        width: @50,
        height: @200
    }
]
```

You can the read the array and create sprites for each rect.

Comment: this would mean i have to add walls manually instead of iterating through a data map, but maybe thats alot easier?

Comment: It can be alot of work to check what the coordinates are for each wall though

Answer (score 0):

they place walls in the .sks file. I believe they are color sprites on transparent with physics body option checked/dynamic unchecked ect.. Each wall is uniquely sized and positioned. They were almost certainly individually placed in the .sks file one by one. this is for the swift version at least